# Best Practice for Unit Testing valid characters

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, vs-unit-testing-framework

Given that a method accepts a string as input parameter and given that this string must only contain numbers from 1 to 8 and a dash ("/").

When developing test driven, how would you write a unit test to validate that the method does a proper argument check?

My first thought was reversing the requirement and testing for an ArgumentException, i.e. having a data driven unit test that calls the method with every other possible character and expects an ArgumentException. However,... that feels a little like cracking nuts with a sledgehammer...

Are there any best practices for situations like that?

Answer (score 3):

> My first thought was reversing the requirement and testing for an ArgumentException

This is the very first thing the function should do. If it is a public function then it should assume that its parameter is invalid until proven otherwise. The requirements you stated are very easily covered with a regex check - if that regex fails then throw an ArgumentException or OutOfRangeException.

> how would you write a unit test to validate that the method does a proper argument check

Two test methods that repeatedly calls the target function are all you need. For the first one have a bunch of calls with a valid parameter, and make sure you check the return value if there is any.
For the second test method fire a bunch of invalid inputs at it, including strings with special characters, upper and lowercase, etc., an invalid input should trigger the exception which will cause the test to fail (you will need to decorate this method with an expected exception attribute).

Comment: This is exactly what I thought. However... would this "bunch of invalid inputs" every single character that could be a possible input character? How do I achieve that?

Comment: @Mephisztoe No you can't realistically do every wrong character - just concentrate on a good sized bunch of inputs that you know fail the validation, whether it be because of length, alpha characters, too many slashes, etc.

Comment: This is one place where you might want to look at Pex - Pex is great to "suggest" a set of good boundary condition cases. http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/

Answer (score 0):

You might try Data-Driven Unit Test (MSDN: [How to: Create a Data-Driven Unit Test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182527%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).

This allows you to define a data source like XML, CSV, or database table and put several kinds of possible inputs into it. The unit test is written only once but is executed once per each data row in your source.

You could populate, e.g. a CSV file with some valid input strings and have it tested, and another CSV file with some invalid strings with a test method checking for `[ExpectedExcetion(typeof(...))]` (or whatever your code should do in this case.)

This is very easy to implement (see the link above) and you could even randomly generate thousands of possible inputs in various formats if you like.